# why some url redirects to random url after DDoS Attack?

Tags: url, random, ddos

My website was under massive DDoS attack.
I was using CloudFlare Pro plan before the attack.

During the attack I have upgraded to Business Plan. I can access my website now but sometimes i have random url redirects like:

When i go to link like: http://example.com/mycss.css
It redirects to random url like: http://example.com/WECU/WEHY/mycss.css

Why?

And how can i resolve that?

And sometimes i get this message "This webpage has a redirect loop" !!

Comment: This is a question for the hosting company support line. Not StackOverflow

Comment: I want to know what type of this attack? And how can I recover from it?